# My website has the Open Graph meta data correctly. Why doesn´t Linkedin show the image?

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

For example, the URL of a page has the og: `<meta property="og:image" content="https://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image.png">`

If I write that URL in LinkedIn that previous image is shown, but if I write the URL `https://url.com/suburl` no image is shown, and the og is the same: `<meta property="og:image" content="https://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/image.png">`

Why does LinkedIn do that? In fact both pages have the og meta data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43567627/3644967

In short, it's likely because you're missing the OG prefix on your page:

```
 <html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
```

Either add it manually, or if you're using a WordPress theme, use a plugin like Complete Open Graph to manage that for you:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/complete-open-graph/