# Open Graph image issue on linkedin

Tags: wordpress, image, tags, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

Im having issues with my project right now regarding linkedin share. The image(thumbnail) doesnt showed up.

My question is, does the url change could also affect?

For example i added the og tags like this:
https://domain_name.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2_About-Team-Photo_New-1.jpg

but when i open up the source code the url was change to:
https://d2gkdq5vdbd74s.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2_About-Team-Photo_New-1.jpg

Does this change affect the Linkedin Share?

By the way the facebook share has no issues at all.

Please help me. Thank you.

Reggards,
gbl

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that your page doesn't have the Open Graph prefix on its  or  tag.

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
```

I believe I've come across that as an issue with LinkedIn shares in the past. As for the URL change, that shouldn't impact it. I believe I've used images from different domains successfully in the past for Open Graph. Do you have a plugin enabled that might be syncing your assets to CloudFront or S3? That might be the cause of that.

I wrote a plugin a while back that might save you some hassle with all of this -- it comprehensively and intelligently adds all of OG tags needed, including the prefix, and allows you to customize that data as you need per page or globally (if you're a developer, you can do this all programmatically with some built-in filters. It also lacks the confusing configuration and bloat of other 'do it all' plugins, which is one of the main reasons I built it. You should check out:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/complete-open-graph/